# How to check variable type given a clang::VarDecl?

Tags: c++, llvm, clang++, clang-tidy, clang-ast-matchers

I am writing a clang-tidy check to automate renaming of some variables of a certain type. I can successfully match their declarations with matcher `varDecl(hasType(asString("class MyType")))`. But then I want to rename these variables and their usages. If I use `FixItHint::CreateReplacement()`, it only replaces names in the declarations, but not in all usages.

I found a `RenamerClangTidyCheck`, which seems to be exactly what I need:

```
/// Base class for clang-tidy checks that want to flag declarations and/or
/// macros for renaming based on customizable criteria.
```

However, it is customized by overriding virtual functions like `getDeclFailureInfo()`, which are called from `ClangTidyCheck::check()` function and they do not have any matchers at hand, they operate with `NamedDecl`. I am only interested in variables declarations, so I can cast it down to `VarDecl`, but then how I make sure this particular `VarDecl` corresponds to a variable with type `MyType`?